# Get file size of a running Windows executable using WQL

Tags: windows, powershell, wql

Is there a way to compute the file size of a Windows process executable using a `WQL` query?

I tried the below but Powershell gave me a management exception.

```
SELECT Caption, ExecutablePath, CommandLine From Win32_Process, (SELECT FileSize FROM Cim_DataFile WHERE Win32_Process.ExecutablePath = Cim_DataFile.Name) as ExecutableSize WHERE ExecutablePath != ''
```

Output from Powershell

> Get-WmiObject : Invalid query At line:1 char:14
>   + Get-WmiObject <<<<  -Query "SELECT Caption, ExecutablePath, CommandLine From Win32_Process, (SELECT FileSize FROM Cim
>   _DataFile WHERE Win32_Process.ExecutablePath = Cim_DataFile.Name) as ExecutableSize WHERE ExecutablePath != ''"
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: No clue, but it's easy enough to do without WMI.  `(gci (gps $process | select -first 1).path).Length`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know this is easily achievable without WQL. But, I have a use-case that just uses WQL.